# Group by time and leaving out GroupBy and only use windowedBy in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to use Kafka Streams to count each time, all the events that happen within a 5 minutes window. I was thinking of using windowedBy but I do not want to group by Key (because I want to take into account all the events no matter of the key), so how can I do this (what should I do in the groupBy())? Or should I maybe take a completely different approach and work with two streams? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by grouping by a constant. So, for example it would look like this: .groupBy((key,value)-> 1) (if the key is an integer)